# How to cache and retrieve Feed data from Firebase Storage in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, caching, firebase-storage

So I'm making an app where one of the view has a canvas view where you can draw images and upload to Firebase Storage image database (under a folder named *Feed Images*), and in the other view you get all the images that was shared by others as well as you. So first thing I gotta do is ask Firestore to get me the list of all items from the child Folder and then use those URL's from the result array it provided me to download the images.

My problem is most of the solutions here tell how to cache on the assumption that you have the urls to images but how do you cache the array of images when you do not have their urls such as in this case?

Also I would like to know a better way to download all files from my 'FeedImages' folder and then listen to my folder for changes and Update the feed accordingly and **Cache!!!** those Images.

Here is my code for my Feed View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

let imageCache = NSCache<AnyObject, AnyObject>()

class FeedVC:  UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout   {
    
    var folderList: [StorageReference]?
    var storage = Storage.storage()
    var downloadedImages : [UIImage] = []
    let cellId = "FeedCell"
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()

        self.storage.reference().child("FeedImages").listAll(completion: {
          (result,error) in
            print("result is \(result.items)")
            self.folderList = result.items
                      DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.folderList?.forEach({ (refer) in
                            self.load(storageRef: refer)
                        })
                          self.collectionView.reloadData()
                      }
                  })
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = .offWhite
        collectionView.delegate = self
//        collectionView.datasource = self
        collectionView.register(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }
    
    //
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return downloadedImages.count ?? 5
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
        if(downloadedImages.count > 0){
            if(downloadedImages[indexPath.row] != nil){
             print("Loading downloaded Image....")
                 cell.img.image = downloadedImages[indexPath.row]
            }
        }
        else{
            cell.img.image = UIImage(named: "Placeholder")
        }

        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (view.frame.width / 3) - 20, height: 100)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10 )
    }
    
    
    func load(storageRef: StorageReference) {
        
        storageRef.downloadURL(completion: {(downloadURL,error) in
            
            // retrieves image if already available in cache
            if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: downloadURL as AnyObject) as? UIImage {
                
                if(self.downloadedImages.count == 0){
                    self.downloadedImages.append(imageFromCache)
                }
                return
            }
            
            
            
            if(error != nil){
                print(error.debugDescription)
                return
            }
//                   print("url is \(downloadURL!)")
            print("Download Started")
            self.getData(from: downloadURL!) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
//                print(response?.suggestedFilename ?? downloadURL!.lastPathComponent)
                print("Download Finished")
                DispatchQueue.main.async() { [weak self] in
                    let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data)
                    self!.downloadedImages.append(imageToCache!)
                    imageCache.setObject(imageToCache as AnyObject, forKey: downloadURL as AnyObject)
                    self?.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
               
            })
    }
    
    func getData(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: completion).resume()
    }

}

class FeedCell :  UICollectionViewCell{
   
    var img = UIImageView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame : frame)
        Setup()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    func Setup(){
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        self.contentView.addSubview(img)
        img.image = UIImage(named: "Placeholder")
        img.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        img.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        img.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        img.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        img.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: The URL is typically used as an identified for the images in the cache. In your case, can you use the path of the image for that purpose?

Comment: Interesting, but don't I have to save my images to disk then? I guess I have a number of sub problems here that needs to be addressed concurrently. Anyway I'll think of a workaround using this approach.